# Why can't std::pair be compared to std::initiliazer_list

Tags: c++, c++14, std-pair, stdinitializerlist

For `std::pair`, I am just curious to know why this works

```
std::pair<int, int> response = {1, 2}
```

while, this doesn't:

```
if (response == {1, 2}) do something;
```

Is it because the operator `=` is overloaded for std::pair while `==` isn't?

Comment: The first one is not an initializer list, while the second one is. Initializer lists cannot be used with pair because initializer list is homogeneous while pair is a heterogeneous data structure. Think about `pair<int, std::string>`

Comment: The first one is not even `operator=`, it is [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just syntax: *braced-init-list* can be an operand **only** to `[]` and `()` (on the inside) and `=` and any `@=` (on the right).  The initialization case is also allowed, where there is no operator at all.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reference on this?

Comment: @Enqueue: I guess you don’t mean the grammar in the standard—cppreference [covers it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) in listing the uses of list-initialization.

Comment: So, list initialization is different than initializer_list and in fact, an object of the latter is automatically created when list initialization is performed or, used as right-operand during assignment. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: @Enqueue: They are different, and *some* list-initialization produces `std::initializer_list<T>` objects, but the contents of a *braced-init-list* can also be used directly (including as constructor arguments).

Answer (score 1):

People have already provided the answer. I would just want to add.

EDIT: The second one is **not** a comparison with an `std::initializer_list` and is invalid syntax actually since something like `{1,2}` doesn't have any inherent *type* as such (try `decltype({1,2}) x`. That's the language's syntax for [`list-initialization`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) which fails since this isn't a statement for *initialization* per se unlike `x{1,2}`/`x = {1,2}`/`foo({1,2})` etc. Something like `{1,2}` can be used to *construct* an `initializer_list` using `list-initialization` but isn't an `std::initializer_list` in itself.

Comaprison operators between an `std::pair` and an `std::initializer_list` are not available and probably for a good reason because an `initializr_list` [is a](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

> lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects
> of type const T.

Note that the type of all the members of an `initializer_list` is of the same type `const T`. This isn't the case for a `pair` that *usually* has distinct types `T` and `U`.

If you want, you could write an equality function between a `pair` and an `initializer_list` something as follows, obviously adhering to many constraints:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename T, typename U>
bool foo(const std::pair<T, U>&pair,
 const std::initializer_list<std::common_type_t<T, U>>& list) {
     if(list.size() != 2) {
         return false;
     }
     auto it = begin(list);
     return pair.first == *it && pair.second == *std::next(it);
}

int main() {
    {
        std::pair<int, int> pair {1, 3};
        std::initializer_list<int> list {1, 2};
        std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<foo(pair, list)<<'\n';
    }
    {
        std::pair<int, int> pair {1, 2};
        std::initializer_list<int> list {1, 2};
        std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<foo(pair, list)<<'\n';
    }
    {
        std::pair<int, int> pair {1, 2};
        std::initializer_list<int> list {1, 2, 3};
        std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<foo(pair, list)<<'\n';
    }
    {
        std::pair<int, char> pair {1, 2}; //common type is int
        std::initializer_list<int> list {1, 2};
        std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<foo(pair, list)<<'\n';
    }
    {
        // std::pair<int, long> pair {1, 2}; //common type is long int
        // std::initializer_list<int> list {1, 2}; //fails template substitution
        // std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<foo(pair, list)<<'\n';
    }
    {
        std::pair<int, long> pair {1, 2}; //common type is long int
        std::initializer_list<long int> list {1, 2}; //same as common type of pair
        std::cout<<std::boolalpha<<foo(pair, list)<<'\n';
    }
    {
        std::pair<int, long> pair {1, 2}; //common type is long int
        if(foo(pair, {1, 2})) {
            std::cout<<"Matched\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s not a comparison to an `initializer_list`: it doesn’t even parse, and if it did it still wouldn’t be an *expression* of that or any other type.

Comment: @DavisHerring You are right. I've changed my answer to reflect that.